# Facebook Page Tab external URL

Tags: facebook

What should contain a HTML file to display it on a Facebook Page's Tab. I have added the tab, but I get blank page, I have tried everything, searched hours, my URL is HTTPS, so I really don't know...

Could you paste anybody a full HTML code that works, appears in a Page's Tab with an app? Thanks!

Comment: Also be aware that Facebook will do a POST request to your server. Make sure it handles that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the answer, the server doesn't enable the iframing, so what I tried was good, but

Console's JavaScript error: `Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.... does not permit cross-origin framing.`

So we contacted to our hosting company to solve this.

UPDATE: Hosting support added the following code to my .htaccess file: `Header always unset X-Frame-Options`, what solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

That would be the minimum, it definitely works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        hello there
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, nothing fancy there. Without any test URL, we can only tell you to open the browser console and search for errors.

Comment: Thank you, in the console we found an error: "Load denied by X-Frame-Options ...", so what I did for an all day long was good, just server doesn't enable that... But thanks!

Comment: a developer should ALWAYS keep the console open, btw ;)